# If $this starts with 'x' in foreach?

Tags: php

i want to match a `$this` value in a `foreach` loop to a string in an `if/else` statement, but I can't seem to get any output? In Javascript this logic should work, but in PHP it doesn't. Every iteration should check if the current value has `$startLetter` as a first letter and, if it does, it should echo that value. If it doesn't start with `$startLetter`, it should not echo that value.

```
<?php
  $clubFeed = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');
  $startLetter = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);

  foreach ($clubFeed->club as $clubAtts) {
     $clubNaam = $clubAtts->naam;

     if(strpos($clubNaam, $startLetter) === 0){
       echo $clubNaam;
     }
  }         
?>
```

Comment: Can you add both example content for feed.xml as the content of $startLetter. Preffered with data accumulated from var_dumps(); Also please var_dump $clubNaam but make sure you parse it to a string first:
var_dump( (string) $clubNaam );

Comment: FYI, `$string[0]` gives you the first character.

Comment: @h2ooooooo and first check if there is a $string[0]. So use `strlen($string)?$string[0]:''`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i don't understand your JS syntax. I'll show you a general example:

```
foreach($clubFeed as $club) {
    if($club->naam[0] == $startLetter[0]) {
        echo $club->naam;
    }
}
```

Single chars in strings can be accessed by there position in the string.

Comment: What do you mean JS syntax?

Answer (score 0):

`parse_url` expects a FULL url, not just the `REQUEST_URI`

```
$url = sprintf("http://%s%s", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$parsed = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

That would be the correct syntax, but since you are using the current url, you could just use:

`$start_letter = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'][0];`